# How to get SNES SmartJoy working on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gamepad

I have an SNES SmartJoy adapter so I can use a SNES controller with emulators but I can't get it working under Ubuntu. Is there a controller configuration utility I need to use?

I'm trying to get it working using the VisualBoy Advance emulator from the standard Ubuntu repository but I'm not having any luck getting a response from that program's controller setup menu.

Answer (score 1):

Well the Smartjoy adapter is [known](http://www.emuparadise.me/reviews/Smartjoy/) to [work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=537143) with [zsnes](http://board.zsnes.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=12253) so my first bet would be to install zsnes. Open your **Software Center** and:

[image]

Install zsnes and test your Smartjoy with it. The links also provide a bug that happened several years ago, but in the case you get it you can simply remove zsnes and install it again or install the **joystick** app:

[image]

which should help you calibrate the joystick.